# Return feedbacks to an API Endpoint while it still running

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl, endpoint

I have a simple API

`http://site/api/script/start?account=5000`

It just a script to create 5000 accounts into my database.

When I hit that API, this code run

```
$add = 0; 

for ($i = 0; $i < $account_total; $i++) {
    
    $max_id = 0;
    $account_id = $max_id+1;
    $url = env('API_HOST').'vse/account';

    $json = '{"account_id":'.$account_id.',"email_address":"'.$type.$account_id.'@benu.com","password":"benu123","account_type":"customer","name_prefix":"","first_name":"'.strtoupper($type).'","middle_names":"","last_name":"'.$account_id.'","name_suffix":"","non_person_name":false,"DBA":"","display_name":"","address1":"","address2":"","address3":"","city":"Boston","state":"MA","postal_code":"02115","nation_code":"USA","phone1":"723487432","phone2":"","phone3":"","time_zone_offset_from_utc":-5,"customer_type":"'.$customer_type.'","longitude":0,"latitude":0,"altitude":0}';
    CURL::post($url,$json);

    echo $add++;
}
```

The code runs well. The accounts are added, but while I made a GET to it

there is `NO` feedback as if the accounts are being added.

It looks plain just like this.

[image]

---

## I'm wondering

if there is a way to return the increment of account as it is being added.

I tried to add `echo $add++;`

It doesn't seem to work.

How would one and go about and achieve something like this?

Comment: you don't have a `ob_start()` somewhere above? And is it the same if you request the script in a browser instead of a rest-client (that what this looks like)?

Comment: Where would `ob_start()` goes ? on top of my file or on top of my function ? Can `ob_start()` achive what I am trying to do ?

Comment: No, ob_start() would prevent what you want. So I was just guessing, couse I don't know yet what causes this...

Answer (score 1):

try

```
flush();
```

after the

```
echo $add++;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Comment: It is not working. I still wait until the end and print all the dots at the end.

Comment: maybe ob_flush();